# node.js pass a callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Currently working :

```
function getAccessToken ( callback ) {

    request({
        uri: oauth2_url,
        method: 'POST',
        form: { 
            grant_type: 'password', 
            client_id: client_id, 
            client_secret: client_secret,   
            username: username, 
            password: password 

        }
    }, 
    function tokenRequestResponse (error, response) { 

        if ( !error && response.statusCode == 200) { 
            // Send our data back to caller.
            callback ( JSON.parse(response.body).access_token );
        }
        else { 
            console.log('Error: ' + response.statusCode); 
        }

    });
}
```

What I'd like to accomplish:

```
function tokenRequestResponse (error, response) { 

        if ( !error && response.statusCode == 200) { 

            callback ( JSON.parse(response.body).access_token );
        }
        else { 
            console.log('Error: ' + response.statusCode); 
        }

}

function getAccessToken ( callback ) {

    request({
        uri: oauth2_url,
        method: 'POST',
        form: { 
            grant_type: 'password', 
            client_id: client_id, 
            client_secret: client_secret,   
            username: username, 
            password: password 

        }
    }, tokenRequestResponse });

}
```

I'd like to avoid nesting tokenRequestResponse() unless that is the only way to have it work with the callback.

It should :

- Create the request
- Upon receiving response, check for errors.
- If errors are not found, send data back to caller of getAccessToken().

This is more of a learning Node.js async question , I've tried a few things and figured I'd ask some experts.

Comment: Could you add the callback function to the tokenRequestResponse call like  `function tokenRequestResponse (error, response)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common way to solve this is to return a function that closes over the `callback`.

So something like this:

```
function tokenRequestResponse(callback) {
    return function (error, response) { 

        if ( !error && response.statusCode == 200) { 

            callback ( JSON.parse(response.body).access_token );
        }
        else { 
            console.log('Error: ' + response.statusCode); 
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
function getAccessToken ( callback ) {

    request({
        uri: oauth2_url,
        method: 'POST',
        form: { 
            grant_type: 'password', 
            client_id: client_id, 
            client_secret: client_secret,   
            username: username, 
            password: password 

        }
    }, tokenRequestResponse(callback));
}
```

When you make the call to `tokenRequestResponse(callback)` the function returns a function that will be used for the `request` callback.

Comment: I get `ReferenceError: error is not defined` , I've tried adding callback as an argument -- but the `error`, `response` parameters also have to be passed in order to determine validity of response.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean.  the `error` and `response` parameters are already passed.

Comment: ahh I made a typo , it's working now. Thanks! the error,response passing "magically" is confusing .

Comment: JavaScript is a functional language!  returning functions is awesome! :)